# Python 2.7.7 not working with RegEx

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, text-parsing, string-parsing

First things first I am not a professional with Regular Expressions and have been depending on  [this cookbook](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch06s11.html), [this tool](http://pythex.org/) and [this other tool](http://pythex.org/)

Now when I try run it it python 2.7.7 64bit win 8 it simply does nothing for this sample text

> Two weeks ago I went shooing at target and spent USD1,010.53 and earned 300 points. When I checked my balance after I only had USD 1912.04.

Note that the USD is joined to the amount (USD1,010.53) and there is a comma for every thousand in the first case but second case it is not joined to the amount and there is no comma for the thousandth place (USD 1912.04) and in some case they are some values which are integers but not currencies and would still need to be parsed.(300 points).

Now I managed to get my hands on this

> [0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(.[0-9]+)?\b|.[0-9]+\b

Now i have two problems:

1. Python doesn't return any value for the above regex and sample string and yet the tools do.
2. the regex will only return if every 1000th place has a comma i.e. the USD 1912.04 ends up returning 912.04 on the online tools not too sure how to have it take both cases of comma and non comma.

`regex = re.compile('[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]+)?\b|\.[0-9]+\b')
 mynumerics = re.findall(regex,'The final bill is USD1,010.53 and you will earn 300 points. Thank you for shopping at Target')`

What I would expect is three items:

```
=>['1,010.53', '300', '1912.04']
```

or better yet

```
=>[1010.53, 300, 1912.04]
```

Instead all i get is an empty list. I could probably try download a different version of python but i know most productions we deploy on use 2.7.X. So i hope its not a version problem.

Comment: It's not a version problem. I tried your code in 3.X and it still didn't work. Also, try using a raw string for your `compile` argument so it doesn't inadvertently read your slashes as the beginning of an escape sequence.

Comment: "Now i have two problems:" ([link](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)) :^)

Comment: Side-note: Even fixed to "work", this pattern will see `4400` and return `400`, or `a123` and return `123`. This may be a problem because if `4400` should be ignored, then you shouldn't get a piece of it (just adding `\b` to the front causes other issues, so it's harder than that), and because [English digit grouping rules allow the omission of the comma when the value is four digits to the left of the decimal, between 1000 and 9999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Exceptions_to_digit_grouping), so `4400` should be accepted as an "English formatted number" and isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two main problems:

- `re.findall` will return a list of tuples if your pattern has any capturing groups in it. Since your pattern is using groups in a very odd way, you will end up seeing some weird results from this. Make use of non capturing groups by using `(?:` instead of just plain `(` parentheses.
- because if the use of `\b`, you should specify your pattern string as a raw string with an `r'string'`. In reality, all of your regex's should use a raw string to ensure that nothing is being parsed weirdly.

With those in mind, this works perfectly fine:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]+)?\b|\.[0-9]+\b')
>>> mynumerics = re.findall(regex,'The final bill is USD1,010.53 and you will earn 300 points. What about .25 and 123,456.12?')
>>> mynumerics
['1,010.53', '300', '.25', '123,456.12']
```

Note some of the particular differences between your pattern and mine.

```
r'[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]+)?\b|\.[0-9]+\b'
1             2             2         
 '[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]+)?\b|\.[0-9]+\b'

1 - raw string
2 - non-capturing groups instead of capturing groups
```

I understand that some of this way go way over your head so please comment if you need clarification and I can edit as needed. I would suggest looking into some other regex references and tips, I personally love [this site](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html) and use it almost religiously for any regex needs.

## EDIT - matching decimals:

As Mark Dickinson cleverly pointed out, the `|\.[0-9]+` in the original regex is for matching things like `.24` (simple decimals). I added that part back in as well as added to the matching string to show the functionality.

## Important Comment from ShadowRanger

**Side-note**: This pattern, as written, will see 4400 and return 400, or a123 and return 123. This is a problem (not @RNar's, the original pattern had the same issue) because if 4400 should be ignored, then you shouldn't get pieces of it (just adding \b to the front causes other issues, so it's harder than that), and because [English digit grouping rules allow the omission of the comma when the value is four digits to the left of the decimal, between 1000 and 9999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Exceptions_to_digit_grouping), so you won't match those as written

Comment: You made one other fix that you didn't call out (escaping the `.`s to `\.`s so they're literals, not "any char"). Otherwise perfect (and this is another example of why I harp on "ALWAYS USE RAW STRINGS FOR REGULAR EXPRESSIONS IN PYTHON!!!"). :-)

Comment: I believe the last part of the original regex is there to match numbers like ".23", without an explicit integral part.

Comment: @ShadowRanger the escape was already in the original matching pattern that he used, if you look at the code that he posted, rather than the pattern he "got his hands on" (theyre not the same)

Comment: And the simplified regex could easily overmatch; if the goal is to recognize groups of 3 matching standard comma separation rules, matching `1,2,3` would be wrong.

Comment: @MarkDickinson aaaahhh I must have been being tripped up from the groupings and parentheses and such. will add it in again.

Comment: @ShadowRanger yeah I know, I stated as such after the pattern. I was already debating whether I should put it in or not so I just edited it out after realizing what it can really match

Comment: Side-note: This pattern, as written, will see `4400` and return `400`, or `a123` and return `123`. This is a problem (not @RNar's, the original pattern had the same issue) because if `4400` should be ignored, then you shouldn't get pieces of it (just adding `\b` to the front causes other issues, so it's harder than that), and because [English digit grouping rules allow the omission of the comma when the value is four digits to the left of the decimal, between 1000 and 9999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Exceptions_to_digit_grouping), so `4400` should be accepted and isn't.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thank you for that, I have added in your comment as an edit to make it more visible to others

Comment: this doesn't work for 1912.04 its just returns 912.04, any ideas?

Comment: this doesn't work for 1912.04 its just returns 912.04 as you described but it is required as various information is formatted differently. How would you suggest i go about it?

Comment: Made some changes this works pretty good but it captures very large numbers which is fine with me. 


([0-9]+([,.]+[0-9]+)*|[0-9]+(\.+[0-9]+)*|(\.+[01]+)*)\b


Thank you all very much @R Nar and @ShadowRanger and everyone who responded. Would you guys recommend me to continue to using regex even for very large diverse short snippets of text like the above. Or should i start to look into semantic parsing or are there any other tools out there to handle such scenarios ?

Comment: sorry about that i meant ([0-9]+([,.]+[0-9]+)*|[0-9])\b

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this regex?

```
((?:\d+,?)+\.?\d+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/qN0gV9/1